# Vuex data just show once then won't display after reloading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

why my json data display just only  once and after reloading the page it won't show again.

Did I miss something here?

```
import axios from "axios";

const store = {
    careers: []
};
const getters = {
    allCareers: (state) => state.careers

};
const mutations = {

    RETRIEVE_CAREERS: (state, career) => (state.careers = career),
};
const actions = {
    async careers({ commit }) {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:9001/career/jobs/');
            commit('RETRIEVE_CAREERS', response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    },
};
export default {
    store,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

and in my component I do this:

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      "allCareers"
      /* more getters here if necessary */
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["careers"])
  },
  created() {
    this.careers();
  }
};
```

and in template I just do this:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <v-card>
      {{allCareers}}
    </v-card>
  </section>
</template>
```

Why it will show only once but won't show after reloading the page?

Comment: any messages in console ?

Comment: in my actions I tried to console.log and successfully retrieves the data but when passing to my component it can't receive the data

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code. Either instrument your code with some logging to gather more insight into what happening or recreate minimal example at site like codesandbox.io and post a link

Comment: try adding 'console.log('created')' to the created hook to test that it is being called when you reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere that you "persist" the fetched data. **Vuex does not persist the data across reloads, it acts as an in-memory storage**

You still have to persist your data to local storage of some sorts like `localStorage` or `indexedDB`.

Here is a simple solution:

```js
const store = {
    careers: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('careers') || '[]');
};

const mutations = {
  RETRIEVE_CAREERS: (state, career) => {
    state.careers = career;
    localStorage.setItem('careers', JSON.stringify(career));
  }
};
```

Comment: Btw its not needed to store data locally if you do load it every time from API (which is exactly whats happening in code in question)...

Comment: True, but I'm not sure if they are talking about why the messages don't appear immediately or not, should've asked for clarification first.